# How to make a scrollable view with UITableViewCells

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of how to make a `UITableView` that doesn't allow scrolling but if the cells exceed the limit of the screen, the user can scroll on the actual `UIViewController` to reach the hidden cells? I have seen this used a lot in apps such as Instagram when you scroll on the Notifications page.

Thank you.

Comment: U need, UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 0):

You may still using `UITableView`.

`tableView.bounces = false` will solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't make it so that the content is scrollable outside of the UITableVIew.